# How to make the text bold using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this out put.

```
<option value="18277">Dollar Max Hospice~Mx</option>
<option value="12979">Routine Adult Physical Exam Visit Limit</option>
<option value="12841">Is Reverse Sterilization Covered Out of Network?</option>
<option value="12918">MD CDH PPO Variables 2</option>
<option value="12917">DC CDH PPO Variables 2</option>
<option value="12833">Is Sterilization Covered No Network?</option>
<option value="12834">Is Sterilization Covered In Network</option>
```

I have a search box and button when i hit Dollar I need to bold the text in my list box. I need to itterate the list box data and make that text as bold.

Comment: I can only see you employ the words **I need** in your question. Nowhere I saw you employing the words **Here's the code I have tried so far to solve the issue but it didn't work**. What you should understand is that we all need some things. But if all start writing about our needs StackOverflow will become like a spam site for expressing needs. Don't you think?

Comment: Could you explain "when I hit Dollar"?  Is the user entering something, and when he hits the dollar sign key (shift-4) you match his entered text with the text in this box?  This seems like odd behavior...

Comment: Thanks CoryKendall, when I enter Variables I need to loop throw all my list box text where I finds the variables I need to make just bold that item.thanks

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Using the jQuery, you can apply the css:

```
font-weight:Bold;
```

So just do:

```
$myElement.css("font-weight","Bold");
```

Comment: How to do I need to for each the select box? my id is lstcode

Comment: `$("#BUTTONID").click(function () { $("Option").css("Font-Weight","Bold") });`

Comment: At least for me worked only when I changed `"Font-Weight","Bold"` to `"font-weight","bold"`.

Answer (score 5):

For me on FF6 at least, it will show as a normal font in the select box, however in the actual list itself it will show bold if you do:

```
$('select option[value="18277"]').css({ 'font-weight': 'bold' });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't bold an individual `<option>` in a `<select>` control. It's annoying, but that's how it is.

Comment: Sorry to bring up an old question, but couldn't you do something like `option[value="foo"] { font-weight: bold }`? I seem to remember setting font weights with classes before, so why not with the value selector?